# Compare view with stream

Tags: view, stream, compare, clearcase

I use ClearCase. I have a snapshot view. Is there a way to compare this view with stream to find changed files?

In TortoiseSVN this is called "Check for modifications" and shows all difference between local copy and what we have in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Clear Case's own possibilities, but you always can make a view of that stream and compare your original view with created one using any file/folder comparison tool. I use [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) for that. There is also an open source tool: [WinMerge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the '[version-tree](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/u_ccvtree.htm)' feature?

Comment: version-tree is not exactly what I am looking for: I want to comapre what I have on disk with repo not to see hostory of one element.